# Multiple database change in a scope throwing error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a method that delete the older files from database based on some conditions:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))
{
    using (var ctx = new ElectronicFileEntities())
    {
        var deleteFilesTime = Int32.Parse(_appSettings["UnFiledDocumentsRetainTime"]);

        var cutOffTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-deleteFilesTime);
        var documentsToDelete = ctx.Documents.Where(o => !o.IsDeleted && !o.IsFiled && o.LastModified < cutOffTime);

        foreach (var document in documentsToDelete)
        {
            _log.InfoFormat("Document to be deleted  {0}", document.DocumentId);
            document.Comment = "Deleted by loader service - not filed in time";
            ctx.DeleteDocument(document.DocumentId, DateTime.Now, 0);
            ctx.InsertDocumentHistory(document.DocumentId, "DELETE");
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

All is well in UAT environment, but started getting error in production.

> Error occurred during method: DeleteOldUnFiledDocuments.
> Error message: The underlying provider failed on Open..
>
> Stack trace:
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<ExecuteFunction>b__49() at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
> at ElectronicFile.Entities.ElectronicCustomerFileEntities.DeleteDocument(Nullable`1 documentId, Nullable`1 lastModified, Nullable`1 lastModifiedBy) in C:\TFS\Main\ElectronicFileService\Entities\ElectronicFile.Context.cs:line 198 at ElectronicFile.ElectronicFileService.DeleteOldUnFiledDocuments() in C:\TFS\Main\ElectronicFileService\ElectronicFileService.svc.cs:line 1651. Inner exception: System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction, Guid promoterType) at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Guid promoterType) at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

I think it can be due to the foreach loop trying to work on multiple records *(  Number of documents to be removed = 7412)*  what is the best way to tackle this issue

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteDocument]
     @DocumentId     INT,
     @LastModified   DATETIME,
     @LastModifiedBy INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE [Document]
        SET IsDeleted = 1,
            LastModified = @LastModified,
            LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy
        WHERE
            DocumentId = @DocumentId
            
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000); 
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT; 
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT; 
     
        SELECT
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(); 
        
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState); 
    END CATCH
END
```

This is the stored procedure for inserting into the history table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDocumentHistory]
     @DocumentId INT,
     @ChangeType VARCHAR(10)    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @ChangeDateTime AS DATETIME
        
        SELECT @ChangeDateTime = LastModified 
        FROM [Document] 
        WHERE DocumentId = @DocumentId
        
        UPDATE DocumentHistory
        SET ActiveTo = @ChangeDateTime
        WHERE DocumentId = @DocumentId
          AND ActiveTo IS NULL
    
        INSERT INTO DocumentHistory (DocumentId, DocumentTypeId, InTrayId, CustomerFileId, ReferenceId,
                                     FileDataId, FileDataType, FileDataSize, FileNoteReference,
                                     EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate, Comment, OriginalFileName, 
                                     IsFiled, IsFlatten, IsVerified, IsDeleted,
                                     ExternalPartyId, ExternalPartyTypeId,
                                     ChangeBy, ChangeType, ActiveFrom) 
            SELECT 
                DocumentId, DocumentTypeId, InTrayId, CustomerFileId, ReferenceId,
                FileDataId, FileDataType, FileDataSize, FileNoteReference,
                EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate, Comment, OriginalFileName,
                IsFiled, IsFlatten, IsVerified, IsDeleted,
                ExternalPartyId, ExternalPartyTypeId, LastModifiedBy,
                @ChangeType, @ChangeDateTime
            FROM
                [Document]
            WHERE
                DocumentId = @DocumentId
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000); 
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT; 
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT; 
     
        SELECT
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(); 
        
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState); 
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things come to mind:
First, this statement:

```
var documentsToDelete = ctx.Documents.Where(o => !o.IsDeleted && !o.IsFiled && o.LastModified < cutOffTime);
```

This will result in an `IQueryable` which will be iterated over, meanwhile your context is expecting to save changes several times within each loop iteration. If you are certain the # of records will be reasonable then try adding a `.ToList()` to the end of that, or a `.Take(100)` or such to grab a reasonable number. I'd be curious what your ElectronicFilesEntities context DeleteDocument() actually does, such as whether it re-retrieves the document by ID.

I'm going on the assumption that this DeleteDocument method sets `IsDeleted = true` and set a Deleted Timestamp?

The next thing would be to remove the multiple calls to SaveChanges. What is the purpose of the TransactionScope? Because the DbContext already will inherently use a transaction for the operations you execute against it. A transaction scope would be more applicable if you wanted to coordinate changes across multiple DbContexts, or between the DbContext and another operation that participates in a transaction scope.

```
using (var ctx = new ElectronicFileEntities())
{
    var deleteFilesTime = Int32.Parse(_appSettings["UnFiledDocumentsRetainTime"]);
    var cutOffTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-deleteFilesTime);
    var documentsToDelete = ctx.Documents
        .Where(o => !o.IsDeleted && !o.IsFiled && o.LastModified < cutOffTime).ToList();

    foreach (var document in documentsToDelete)
    {
        document.Comment = "Deleted by loader service - not filed in time";
        ctx.DeleteDocument(document.DocumentId, DateTime.Now, 0);
        ctx.InsertDocumentHistory(document.DocumentId, "DELETE");
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

A better pattern IMO for something like this is DDD (Domain-Driven Design)  Document contains a method called "Delete" which is responsible for accumulating all appropriate actions.

I.e.

```
public void Delete(string comment)
{
    Comment = comment;
    IsDeleted = true;
    DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
    History.Add(new DocumentHistory
    {
       Action = "DELETE",
       // ...
    });
}
```

Then the logic to mark the documents as deleted becomes:

```
using (var ctx = new ElectronicFileEntities())
{
    var deleteFilesTime = Int32.Parse(_appSettings["UnFiledDocumentsRetainTime"]);
    var cutOffTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-deleteFilesTime);
    var documentsToDelete = ctx.Documents
        .Include(o => o.History)
        .Where(o => !o.IsDeleted && !o.IsFiled && o.LastModified < cutOffTime).ToList();

    foreach (var document in documentsToDelete)
        document.Delete("Deleted by loader service - not filed in time");

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The caveat here is if the Document History is a collection under the document, in which case we would want to eager load it or risk a lazy load when adding the new history. If the history isn't available on the entity, or poses a potentially large set to pull data from and we want to keep it separate then I'd suggest using a repository pattern rather than using the DbContext unless that context is bounded to serve just these related entities/operations. Otherwise the # of methods the context exposes to perform actions like deleting will grow quite large.

If you do go down the context-to-delete path where the document history is not directly referenced by the document, then I'd recommend consolidating the delete into a DDD-like operation:

```
// In Document entity...
public void Delete(string comment)
{
    Comment = comment;
    IsDeleted = true;
    DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
    // no history reference.
}

// in DbContext
public Document DeleteDocument(Document document, string comment)
{
    document.Delete(comment);
    DocumentHistory.Add(new DocumentHistory
    {
       Document = document,
       Action = "DELETE",
       // ...
    });
}
```

then in your code to iterate through the documents to delete:

```
foreach (var document in documentsToDelete)
    ctx.DeleteDocument(document, "Deleted by loader service - not filed in time");
```

A good article on DDD approaches with EF: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/creating-domain-driven-design-entity-classes-with-entity-framework-core/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will try the first suggestion

Comment: The first method failed in prod environment when  the data to be updated count was 7412    foreach (var document in documentsToDelete)
                            {
                                _log.InfoFormat("Document to be deleted  {0}", document.DocumentId);
                                document.Comment = "Deleted ";
                                ctx.DeleteDocument(document.DocumentId, DateTime.Now, 0);
                                ctx.InsertDocumentHistory(document.DocumentId, "DELETE");
                            }
                            ctx.SaveChanges();

Comment: Ok, can you update your question with the methods DeleteDocument and InsertDocumentHistory?  Also, what is the exception now? The same issue about an open transaction?

Comment: Ok, so you have stored procedures to modify the document and copy it across to the historical table. Can you also add the code for the methods in your DbContext that calls these Sprocs?

Answer (score 0):

Final Working solution . moved the Commit inside the for loop

```
  foreach (Document document in documentsToDelete)
                    {
                        using (var dbContextTransaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                document.Comment = "Deleted by loader service - not filed in time";
                                ctx.SaveChanges();

                                ctx.DeleteDocument(document.DocumentId, DateTime.Now, 0);
                                ctx.SaveChanges();

                                ctx.InsertDocumentHistory(document.DocumentId, "DELETE");
                                ctx.SaveChanges();

                                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                                var message = string.Format("Error occurred during method: {0}. Error message: {1}. Stack trace: {2}. Inner exception: {3}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
                                _log.ErrorFormat(message);
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

`